# How to determine or set keyboard shortcut for activities view in gnome3 on centos7?

Tags: centos, gnome3

Is there a way in Gnome3 on CentOS7 to list the actual keyboard shortcuts for things like the activities view?  I can find lots of web pages that tell me what they should be, but I'd like to know for sure.

For instance, a "Gnome Help" site says that the shortcut for the activities view is "Alt-F1", but that just brings up the Application menu.  I want a shorter sequence to bring this up.  That same page also refers to a "Super" key, but I don't have that key on this HP "Z Book".

After I get a list of these shortcuts, how can I change them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see all shortcuts under "Keyboard" in the "Settings" and add custom ones.

And you can change the key for the applications menu in the Gnome Tweak Tool.

Comment: Got it. Answers that question. That now results in a new question, which I'll post separately, but no matter what key binding I set for the "activities overview", it only shows the applications menu.

Comment: I added the hint to the tweak tool. Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the application menu then the `Alt + F1` shortcut should open the activities overview.

Disable the application menu:
Tweaks -> Extensions -> Applications menu -> set to OFF.